# Seeking GIS that can calculate fractal dimensions?

Tags: software-recommendations

As ‘Fractals are Everywhere’ in geo-ref data, which GIS other than ArcGIS
can calculate fractal dimensions?

Comment: It looks like Grass has it, although a bug was just fixed: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3102

Answer (score 12):

QGIS could too via a plugin it seems :

- [Minkowski fractal dimension calculation for vector layer features](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/minkowskiDimCalculator/)

SAGA GIS seems a good candidate : [Library Fractals](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/garden_fractals.html)

```
- Bifurcation
- Fractal Dimension of Grid Surface
- Gaussian Landscapes
- Mandelbrot Set (interactive)
- Newton-Raphson (interactive)
- Pythagoras' Tree
```

As @mkennedy mentions there's GRASS too :

- [r.surf.fractal - Creates a fractal surface of a given fractal dimension.](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.surf.fractal.html)

I know you exclude Arcgis, but just for generic info, it seems it has some add-on tools that could help :

- [Hawth tools / Line metric tool : allows the user to calculate Sinuosity or Fractal Dimension](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/linemetrics.php)